# How to disable City names in Bing Maps V8

Tags: bing-maps, bing

[image]

I've got the following map on my website initialised from js.
How do I disable city names like how other countries are shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom style as shown in the sample below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    
    <script>
    var map;
    var hiddenCityLabels = {
        "version": "1.0",
        "elements": {
            "point": {
                "labelVisible": false,
                "visible":false
            }
        }
    };

    function GetMap()
    {
        map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap', {
            customMapStyle: hiddenCityLabels
        });
    }
    </script>
    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myMap" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:600px;"></div>

     <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap&key=<Your Bing Maps Key>'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing the documentation for this? I couldn't find map control parameters. I also wanna hide roads

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/articles/custom-map-styles-in-bing-maps